# Tests if means between factors are significantly different

Tags: mean, factor-analysis

After performing a factor analysis and grouping a set of 20+ questions into 3 different factors, we can then calculate a mean, std dev etc for each of these sets of questions or in other words, per grouped factor.

Which test should be used to determine if there are significant differences between the means of these factors?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. (If, for example, you performed FA in a sample and extracted 2 factors, there is no sense to compare these two factors with each other; btw, both means are supposed to be 0.)